# Connect ETIMEDOUT error running an Azure App Service deploy task in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've noticed this error after an unsuccessful deploy.

It happened on 2 `Azure App Service deploy` tasks.
Both of them deploy to a `staging` slot. One deploys a continuous webjob and the other deploys an app service.

The error is the following:
`Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'xxxxxx' publishing credentials. Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.69.229.235:443`

This seems to be a rare error. I just wonder whats the reason behind it.

[image]

Comment: From what i investigated it might be due to a timeout trying to executing the deploy command (?). A solution might be to increase the idle timeout ```SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT=600```

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I'm experiencing the same issue.